How Do I Use Nextjs i18n Internationalisation For localhost?
I am looking to organise subdomains for my app, where I can have the translations for them. E.g. en.example.com is for the English landing page. However, before I push to my repo, I want to test to see whether it works on localhost:3000. How can I achieve that using the pages route?
next.config.js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  i18n: {
    locales: ["en-US", "fr"],
    defaultLocale: "en-US",
    domains: [
      {
        domain: "en.example.com",
        defaultLocale: "en-US",
      },
      {
        domain: "fr.example.com",
        defaultLocale: "fr",
      },
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;

next-i18next.config.js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: "en-US",
    locales: ["en-US", "fr"],
    localeDetection: true,
  },
  localePath: path.resolve("./public/locales"),
};

text.jsx
import { serverSideTranslations } from "next-i18next/serverSideTranslations";
import { useTranslation } from "next-i18next";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

function Text() {
  const router = useRouter();
  console.log("router: ", router); // It thinks the local is "en-US", so it isn't working for http://fr.localhost:3000/test
  const { t } = useTranslation("common");

  return <h1>{t("greeting")}</h1>;
}

export default Text;

// This gets called on every request
export async function getServerSideProps({ locale }) {
  return {
    props: {
      // Load the 'common' namespace for the current locale
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ["common"])),
    },
  };
}

package.json
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -H 0.0.0.0"

